# Accessing "Include attachments" from the Lightning for Outlook plugin

Tags: lightning-aura-components, attachment, lightning-for-outlook

I do have a custom Lightning component on my Lightning for Outlook interface. This has a basic input form which just creates a new record on the Salesforce.

Whenever an email with an attachment(s) gets in, on the Lightning for Outlook plugin's footer, there is this standard(OOB) feature: **Include attachments** checkbox, which gets enabled.

[image]

How can I access this attachment(s) source to push along with the new record creation? I tried looking in the internet, but couldn't get any documentation or resources.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for now it's not possible. I created an idea for that, you can add your voice and vote for it [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003VrFQAU).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I saw that already. Its been five months since you posted. Haven't you heard anything from the Salesforce? Also have you tried contacting support via your Production org or any other way?

Comment: I talked to the PM at the time and it was not on the immediate roadmap.

Comment: Wow. How about any other ways of accessing the attachments? Is there a way to access using JavaScript function or something like that?

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it, but if you find one at some point please share :)

Comment: Okay, let me try to connect with the Salesforce and see if I can find a way.